# Saving data from javascript button

Tags: javascript, button, save

I have simple button on my page and I want to ask - What is the best way to save or count every click on this button? - Is it text file? Is it some internet server? I am very new to JS, thanks. - demo is here:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('like');
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.className = 'after';
});
```

```css
.like{
  color: red; 
}
.like:hover{
  color: blue;
}
.after{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
Do you like this page? Please click button bellow.
<button class="like" id="like">CLICK!</button>
```

Comment: That depends, where do you want to save this to and who needs to see this? Does only the user that clicked the button need to know about the count?

Comment: I think if you only want to count per user you can do it with js locally, but if its every time someone goes to the page and click you need to use a server

Comment: Only one who needs to see it its me - as webmaster - normal users browsing page could not see it. It could also be saved anywhere - just for me to have acces to check the number that increases everytime someone clicks button on page.

Comment: @Franck it could be per user, after refresh page they can click again, it doesn't matter :)

Comment: If you need all users then google analytics is simplest...doesn't require you to build a secure admin page to read it or set up datbase on your server or third party service. It's free and only takes a few minutes to get it set up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById('like');
var timesClicked = 0;
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.className = 'after';
    timesClicked += 1;
});
```

Comment: well but it resets after page refresh, could it be did without restarting counter at page refresh?

Comment: @Arbys No, if you want something to not reset on page refresh you'll need to store it with cookies or use the web server, and if you (as the host) want to be able to see the number of clicks from all users, you'll *have* to use the web server

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work that way. Like Nick said, you'll need more advanced stuff like databases. Cookies would be the easiest way for you to do this, but it might not be the perfect solution. Please mark the answer as correct if it helped, but what you're asking is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.